# add a non-comparable object to a set 

Tags: c++, data-structures, set

i have a class named Point (in an external library, i can't modify the code) that is used to represent a point in a 3d space:

```
int x = 0; int y = 0; int z = 0;
Point my_point p(x,y,z);
```

It overloads the `==` and `!=` operators but not `<` or `>` ones. I need to store them in an efficient way (no double element, no repetition). I thought my data structure is `set`, but if i try to use, i get this error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__x < __y’
```

some advice?

Comment: @TomQuarendon: It's probably not a good idea to define a universal `operator<` for a multi-dimensional point, since there are many possible orderings. It would be better to choose an ordering for the set to use, and provide  a custom comparator for that ordering.

Answer (score 5):

Write a comparison operator, and instantiate the `set` with that:

```
struct ComparePoints
{
    bool operator()( Point const& lhs, Point const& rhs ) const
    {
        if ( lhs.x != rhs.x ) {
            return lhs.x < rhs.x;
        } else if ( lhs.y != rhs.y ) {
            return lhs.y < rhs.y;
        } else {
            return lhs.z < rhs.z;
        }
    }
};

std::set <Point, ComparePoints> mySet;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define a comparison functor and pass it as second template argument to std::set. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), look at `Compare`. You can also define `bool operator<(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs)`, but if you cannot touch the class, this requires that the comparison can be implemented via the public interface of `Point`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define operator < yourself. It doesn't have to be inside the Point class if x, y and z are available from Point's public interface.

```
bool operator<(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs)
{
  if( lhs.x != rhs.x ) return lhs.x < rhs.x;
  if( lhs.y != rhs.y ) return lhs.y < rhs.y;
  return lhs.z < rhs.z;
}
```